# MongoDB Stitch error: Inserting item, no rule exists for namespace

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

Using MongoDB Stitch with my iOS App, an authenticated user can't write to the database – the error in the log (and the console) reads as `no rule exists for namespace`.

Find screenshots of my configuration and the log attached – any help is much appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried setting up stitch once and got into the same problem. Just make sure if the (databasename) or (collectionname) is matching with what you are using in your script. Or just try deleting the collection from there and create a new one.

Comment: This was my issue. I had created the collection but in the wrong cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure MongoDB Realm/Stitch for access the collection. Make sure your changes are saved/deployed.

Comment: Okay. But how? I thought I had done that. :sweat_smile: